# Pie Chart R programming

Tags: r, plot

Create a pie chart for the top 6 entries of the mtcars dataset. Plot the `mpg` values against the row names(labels) of the dataset.
I tried with this code but may be I am not able to understand the question correctly as in katacoda environment I am not able to move forward.
Code:

```
count = table(mtcars$mpg[1:6])
pie(count)
```

[image]

Comment: "top 6" mpg but none of the answers are sorting anything: `x <- setNames(mtcars$mpg, rownames(mtcars)); x <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE); pie(x[1:6])`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `table`, which would *count* the number of equal values, the variable `mpg` is continuous.
The question asks to plot the top 6 *values* of `mpg` against `row.names(mtcars)`.

```
x <- setNames(mtcars$mpg[1:6], row.names(mtcars)[1:6])
pie(x)
```

[image]

Comment: @user7826397 What is not correct? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe highcharter?

```
highchart() %>% 
hc_add_series(data=cbind(name=rownames(mtcars),mtcars)[1:6,],
type="pie",hcaes(name=name,y=mpg))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly odd plot (I'm not sure I fully understand what you're going for), but you should be able to adapt this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

mtcars_sub <- head(mtcars, 6)
mtcars_sub$names <- rownames(mtcars_sub)

ggplot(mtcars_sub) +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1, amount = mpg, fill = names), stat = "pie")
```

Although I far prefer this as a bar chart. I think its much more interpretable

```
ggplot(mtcars_sub) +
  geom_col(aes(y = mpg, x = names, fill = names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these set of commands

```
data(mtcars)
pie(table(mtcars$mpg[1:6]),labels=row.names(mtcars)[1:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data(mtcars)
count <- table(mtcars$mpg[1:6])
pie(count, labels = row.names(mtcars)[1:6])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation.

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please add an explanation of how this works and why it is supposed to help.